# using a predicate with fetch without a tableView

Tags: ios, core-data

To learn about Core Data, I'm making a quiz app but it doesn't use a table view. I have the data for two quizzes seeded in the application. When a user clicks on a button on the view, I want to fetch a quiz, depending on which button he/she presses, but I'm not sure what I can put in for the predicate

```
       if ([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"sports"]){

        NSError *error;
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Quizdata"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(SELF = %@)", ????];  ///unsure what to put here
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        self.fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        NSLog(@"fetched object %@", fetchedObjects);

    }else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"entertainment"]){
        NSLog(@"entertainment%@", sender.currentTitle);
    }
```

I have two entities, for example Quiz.h, which I made classes for based on the attributes of the entities

```
@dynamic quizId;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic quizData;
```

and a QuizData.h entity

```
@dynamic answer1;
@dynamic answer2;
@dynamic answer3;
@dynamic answer4;
@dynamic correctAnswer;
@dynamic question;
@dynamic score;
@dynamic unique;
@dynamic quiz;
```

I had hoped to be able to fetch one of the two quizzes by doing something similar to what I'd do in Rails

```
Quizdata.where(quizId => 1)
```

Is it possible to only fetch the sports questions the way that I've done it (i.e. without using a table view). The reason why I thought tableView might be important is that it'll have object ids. I can't figure out how to get CoreData to retrieve every question for quizId 1.

I had previously imported data like this with json

```
{ "question" : "Do you like basketball", "answer1": "yes", "answer2": "no", "answer3": "maybe", "answer4":"of course", "correctAnswer": "yes", "unique": "2", "name": "sportsquiz", "quizId": "1"},
```

and then inserted and saved it with the two classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure ...

I don't completely follow the logic on your Model As i'm not seeing a relationship between Quiz and QuizData.

If you had one, you would have an NSSet in Quiz containing a collection of QuizData. The you would simply perform an NSFetchRequest like this;

```
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Quiz" inManagedObjectContext:context];
   [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"quizId >= %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
   [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

FetchedObjects would contain an array of "Quiz" objects whose quizId >= 1. If you had set up your relationships correctly, each quiz object would contain a collection of quizData objects.

The main thing to remember is that Core Data is an Object Graph. As such, you would add quizData Objects to your Quiz object (as opposed to setting a relationship field and adding the relationship key to the Quiz object).